# Flask from .models import * giving "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, flask, import, package, importerror

When in my app.py, I am trying to import something from models.py and when I use

```
from .models import *
```

but I'm receiving the following error on my shell

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

My directory tree looks as following:

```
└── PROJECT_FOLDER
    ├── README.md
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── app.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── app.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── scraping.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── scraping.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── app.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── models.py
    ├── scraping.py
    ├── static
    │   └── css
    │       ├── bootstrap-theme.min.css
    │       ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │       ├── sign.css
    │       └── theme.css
    └── templates
        ├── base.html
        └── index.html
```

I've tried putting a main.py in an outer folder and importing  `from PROJECT_FOLDER.models import *`
but that hasn't worked.
I also have tried putting an `__init__.py` in my root directory.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it without the '.'? That is, from models import *

Comment: im getting the following error when i do:"Unresolved reference 'models' "